# PHP MSSQL : How to display output when query return no row

Tags: php, sql-server

i have a problem with my PHP-MSSQL query.
i have a join table that need to give a result something be like this:

```
    Department        Group A              Group B           Total A+B
                 WORKHOUR A OTHOUR A    WORKHOUR B OTHOUR B      WORKHOUR  OTHOUR
    HR             10         15     25   0               35       15
    IT              5          5                               5        5
    Admin                                    12   12              12       12
```

the query will count how many employee as per given date (admin will enter data and once submitted, the query will give the above result).

The problem is, the final output is a mess when there's no row to be displayed. the column is **shifted to the right**.

i.e: 
only Group A in IT
only Group B in Admin

```
Department        Group A              Group B           Total A+B
             WORKHOUR A OTHOUR A WORKHOUR B OTHOUR B      WORKHOUR  OTHOUR
HR      10       15       25     0               35      15
IT       5        5        5         5
Admin   12       12       12        12
```

my question is, how to prevent this to happen?
i've tried everything with While.... if else.. but the result is still the same. 
**how to display output "0" if no rows to return?**
        echo "0";

this is my QUERY:

```
    select DD.DPT_ID,DPT.DEPARTMENT_NAME,TU.EMP_GROUP, sum(DD.WORK_HOUR) AS  WORK_HOUR,      
    sum(DD.OT_HOUR) AS OT_HOUR
    FROM DEPARTMENT_DETAIL DD
    left join DEPARTMENT DPT
    ON (DD.DEPT_ID=DPT.DEPT_ID)
    LEFT JOIN TBL_USERS TU
    ON (TU.EMP_ID=DD.EMP_ID) 
    WHERE DD_DATE>='2012-01-01'
    AND DD_DATE<='2012-01-31'
    AND TU.EMP_GROUP!=2
    GROUP BY DD.DEPT_ID, DPT.DEPARTMENT_NAME,TU.EMP_GROUP
    ORDER BY DPT.DEPARTMENT_NAME
```

this is one of the logic that i've used, but doesn't return the result that i want::

```
    while($row = mssql_fetch_array($displayResult))
{


if ((!$row["WORK_HOUR"])&&(!$row["OT_HOUR"]))

{
echo "<td >";
echo "empty";
echo "&nbsp;</td>";

echo "<td >";
echo "empty";
echo "&nbsp;</td>";

}
else 

{
echo "<td>";
echo $row["WORK_HOUR"];
echo "&nbsp;</td>";

echo "<td>";
echo $row["OT_HOUR"];
echo "&nbsp;</td>";

}



}
```

please help. i've been doing this for 2 days. @__@

Comment: what is the php code? would it be the problem of the php logic?

Comment: I wrote an answer to solve a problem in SQL because you only pasted SQL code.  But your problem is a PHP/Markup problem!  We can't fix that without the code you're using to generate the output!

Comment: you can also use SELECT IFNULL(my_column,0) this will produce 0 if the result of column is null

Comment: @raheelshan That was my original answer, but because this is a presentation issue I deleted it.

Comment: @LiangliangZheng : I've added the php code above. it doesn't work. pls help.

Comment: @GordonM: yes. my logic is the problem. i've tried almost everything. hope i can find answer in here.

Comment: @raheelshan : select ifnull? how?

Comment: sorry i thought you are using mysql it is a function of mysql try to find alternate function of sql-server

Comment: the problem is only the logic. i don't know why the "empty" doesn't get displayed when both of the rows are zero. (WORK_HOUR & OT_HOUR). but it gets displayed if either of it is zero.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I didn't misunderstand your question. The reason you got some rows missing is that you didn't even get any tup for some cases.

For instance, if I have a simple table t1(key1 varchar(200), key2 varchar(200), val integer),
and I wrote a query like `select key1, key2, sum(val) from t1 group by key1, key2;`

Assume that the values were -

```
apple week1 4
apple week2 5
pear  week1 3
pear  week1 3
apple week2 3
apple week2 4
apple week1 5
```

With the query, I would never get something like (pear, week2) => some value.

Similarly, you might not even trigger the conditional check like `(!$row["WORK_HOUR"])&&(!$row["OT_HOUR"])`

I hope the code below would help.

```
$results = array();

$allDepts = array();
$allGroups = array();

while($row = mssql_fetch_array($displayResult))
{
    $deptId = $row['DPT_ID'];
    $deptName = $row['DEPARTMENT_NAME'];
    $group = $row['EMP_GROUP'];
    $workHours = $row['WORK_HOUR'];
    $otHours = $row['OT_HOUR'];

    // set up a thorough list of depts & groups
    $allDepts[$deptId] = $deptName;
    $allGroups[$group] = $group;

    // store the values of hours
    $results[$deptId][$group]['work'] = $workHours;
    $results[$deptId][$group]['ot'] = $otHours;
}

// go through all possible combination of (dept, groups)
foreach($allDepts as $deptId => $deptName) {
    echo "<tr><td>$deptName</td>\n";
    foreach($allGroups as $group) {
        $workHours = $results[$deptId][$group]['work'];
        printTd($workHours);
        $otHours = $results[$deptId][$group]['ot'];
        printTd($otHours);
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}

function printTd( $value ) {
    $value = $value ? $value:"empty";
    echo "<td>$value</td>\n";
}
```

Comment: this is great. but how to sum for the total? i need to calculate the total work hour , total ot for each row (department) (at the most right column) and then to return the grand total at the bottom of each column. (i'm really not fluent with array)

Comment: you can assign a new array $totals[ $deptName ][ 'work' or 'ot' ], and add the $workHours & $otHours to this array. Let me know if it is not clear

Comment: okay. definitely not clear. i'm able to calculate the final Grand Total for WorksHour & OT Hours at the bottom of the table , but i still have no idea on how to display total by each row. (Total WorkHour Group A&B), (Total OT Group A&B)

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($rec))
{
   $arr[] = $r;
}

if(count($arr) == 0){
echo 0;
}else{
//do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

phew. finally, using @LiangLiang Zheng answer, i could get the final grand total and the Work Hours & OT Hours  for each line (row in view).  (seriously, i only know basic, simple PHP, and don't really know how to use array, etc. so i only code whatever in my knowledge).

The only thing left that i need to do right now is to display the grand total for EACH COLUMN: 
**Total Work Hour Group A, Total OT Hour Group A,Total Work Hour Group B, Total OT Hour Group B**. (anyone can help me on this?)

anyway, here how i got the Total Work Hour & Total OT Hour for each line/row and the final Grand Total for both Work Hours & OT hours (to display at the bottom of the table):

```
    <?php

    $total_workhours=0;
    $total_ot=0;
    // go through all possible combination of (dept, groups)
    foreach($allDepts as $deptId => $deptName) {

    $dept_workhour=0;
$dept_ot=0;

    echo "<tr><td>$deptName</td>\n";

    foreach($allGroups as $group) 
{
    $workHours = $results[$deptId][$group]['work'];
    printTd($workHours);
    $otHours = $results[$deptId][$group]['ot'];
    printTd($otHours);

    $total_workhours+=$workHours;
    $total_ot+=$ot_hour;

            $dept_workhour +=$workHours;
    $dept_ot +=$ot_hour;

    }

echo "<td> $dept_workhour</td>\n";
echo "<td>$dept_ot</td>\n";
    echo "</tr>\n";
    }
    ?>
    <tr align="center">
    <td>TOTAL</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td ><?php echo $total_workhours; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $total_ot; ?></td>
    </tr>

    <?php
    function printTd( $value ) {
    $value = $value ? $value:"empty";
    echo "<td>$value</td>\n";
    }
```

Comment: 1. This is really an insult to someone who tried to help you. You should *NOT* just grab the answer & most of the code and create your own answer.

Comment: 2. If you try to answer your own question, at least make sure that it is clear & correct. e.g., what is on earth "$ts_hour"?

Comment: @LiangliangZheng, i'm sorry, but i did put "using LiangLiang Zheng answer". actually, it's workhour, not ts_hour. sorry.. my bad.